# How can I find/simulate mixed-ancestry DNA data?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, human-genetics, population-genetics, recombination

Some collaborators and I are building an ancestral inference tool, and we're having trouble obtaining reliable ground-truth data for samples of mixed ancestry. All the ground-truth DNA datasets we're aware of (Thousand Genomes, Simons Foundation) are from persons reported as unequivocally belonging to some population (East Asian, African/African-American, South Asian, or even something specific like Somali, Icelandic or Cambodian.)

But we can't find any samples that are attestedly mixed-ancestry. We've thought about just generating simulated data using VCFs from two persons of different known ancestries, but we're not sure how to account for the non-random aspects of recombination, which are described here:
https://www.bio-itworld.com/news/2019/03/06/latest-genetic-map-finds-recombination-is-not-so-random
And we don't know of any tools that could perform this task for us.

Does anyone have suggestions for obtaining/simulating DNA data for persons of mixed ancestry? This is a natural enough problem that we suspect others must have encountered it also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Price et al 2009](https://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1000519#s2) describe how to simulate admixed genomes in this paper.

> We constructed 40 haploid admixed genomes (n = 1 to 40) from the 40
> haploid Yoruba and 40 haploid French genomes by using haploid Yoruba
> genome n and haploid French genome n to construct admixed genome n, so
> that ancestral genomes were never reused. To construct an admixed
> genome, we began at the first marker on each chromosome and sampled
> French ancestry with probability α and Yoruba ancestry with
> probability 1-α. Ancestry was resampled based on an exponential
> distribution with weight λ (the number of generations since admixture)
> so that a new ancestry was sampled with probability 1−e−λg when
> traversing a genetic distance of g Morgans. Each time ancestry was
> resampled, we sampled French ancestry with probability α and Yoruba
> ancestry with probability 1-α. For each individual, we used a value of
> α to apply to the entire genome by sampling from a beta distribution
> with mean 0.20 and standard deviation 0.10 (typical for African
> Americans [4])

You could apply this method to e.g. .bam/.vcf files from SGDP and use the sampled ancestry as regions in the .bam/.vcf file from different ethnicities.